# Duplicate column name in SQLite for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to create a table using SQLite for Windows Phone:

```
[Table("Accounts")]
public class Account : ObservableObject
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private double balance;

    [Column("id"), PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set { Set(() => ID, ref id, value); }
    }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { Set(() => Name, ref name, value); }
    }

    [Column("balance")]
    public double Balance
    {
        get { return this.balance; }
        set { Set(() => Balance, ref balance, value); }
    }
}

Connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("database.sqlite");

await Connection.CreateTableAsync<Account>();
```

The CreateTableAsync method raises SQLiteException with a message "duplicate column name: id". What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use `[Ignore]` attribute for such properties which are not intended as table column

Comment: The id property is intended as table column. Futhermore, I've created new project in MVS2013 with the same code as above and no exceptions have been raised.

Comment: Add `[Ignore]` for `private int id;` no for `ID`.

Comment: It is not possible to add `[Ignore]` for private property. And as I said, **no exceptions have been raised in new project**.